# Gargeya Gotra / Gargi Gotra

Tags: gotra

My Surname is Yadav and my  gotra is Gargeya . Is that possible because Gargeya are Suryavanshi lineage and Yadav are Chandravanshi lineage. I am confused. I am from Maharashtra if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well as you can see from the screen shot below & [here](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/garga) that Bhuvamanyu (भुवमन्यु).— A son of Vitatha, and father of four powerful sons, Bṛhadkṣatra and three others including Garga, was the successor of King Bharata who was a Chandravanshi.

[Refer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bharata_(emperor))

> According to the Mahābhārata (Adi Parva), Bharata was the son of King
>   Dushyanta and Shakuntala and thus a descendant of the Lunar dynasty of
>   the Kshatriya Varna.

[image]

But I found [another](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/gargya) definition that matches the gotra you are seeking:

> Gārgya (गार्ग्य):—Son of Śini (son of Garga).  Although Gārgya was a
>   kṣatriya, there came from him a generation of brahmaṇas. (see
>   Bhāgavata Purāṇa 9.21.19-20)

So Garga are from Chandravanshi lineage.

Comment: Can you please revise your answer...there is really a serious issue..king Bharata was NOT from Yadvas (Yadu's lineage) ..he was from Pauravas ( lineage of Puru)... As questioner says he is Yadav so how come his gotra  from Pauravas..

Comment: @yds I stated he was a Chandravanshi not Suryavanshi

Comment: Chandravanshi is a bigger group..If he is Yadav i.e. lineage of king Yadu (in which Haihaya, Kartavirya Arjuna, Madhu, Vrishni  and Lord Shri Krishna incarnated) then your answer is NOT appropriate..that's what i think...

Comment: @YDS Well I concluded from what I read not what I knew before hand.

Comment: Well...u din't prove how the lineage of this Garga are known as Yadava..? As u have already seen https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10873/who-was-maharshi-garga that same gotra is in brahmins too... so whatever u quoted seems a gotra in Pauravas and not in Yadavas..

Comment: I didn't prove that Garga are Yadav, I stated that successor of Bharata (Chandrvanshi) was Bhuvamanyu who had son named Garga, so ideally a Chandravanshi succeeds a Chandravanshi?

Comment: Did you read very first line.."My Surname is Yadav and my gotra is Gargeya" - I believe questioner wants clarification on this?..